# Finding all supersets in a list of sets

Tags: set, common-lisp, reduce

The following function aims to return all of the supersets in a list of sets--ie, remove any set that is a subset of any other set in the list. So (supersets '((1 2) (1 2 3) (3 2) (3 5) (5 3))) -> ((1 2 3) (3 5)). Is there a more elegant/efficient way to think about how to do this? It would seem to roughly fit the common-lisp "reduce" model, except that two non-overlapping sets simply reduce to themselves. Thanks for any simplifications or insights:

```
(defun supersets (sets)
  (let ((remaining-sets sets))
    (loop for set1 in sets
      do (loop for set2 in (set-difference remaining-sets (list set1))
           when (subsetp set1 set2)
            do (setq remaining-sets
                     (set-difference remaining-sets (list set1)))
               (return))
      finally (return remaining-sets))))
```

Comment: Why is `(3 5)` considered a superset, but `(5 3)` is not?

Comment: @jkiiski It can make sense considering that `(3 5)` and `(5 3)` denote the same set and we don't mind removing duplicates. Note also that since the value appears twice in the list, we could say that "remove any set that is a subset of any other set" would imply that `(3 5)` should not appear in the result, because it is subset of itself. But I guess the intended meaning of "other" in the question is "strictly different". The list of sets seems to  be treated as a set itself here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient solution can be found by using three primitive functions:

```
(defun supersets (sets)
  (delete-duplicates (sort (copy-list sets) #'<= :key #'length) :test #'subsetp))
```

First the list is sorted on the length of its elements (`copy-list` is needed since `sort` destructively modifies its parameter), so that we have now a list of sets in ascending order of length, so that each set can be a subset only of a following element.

Then we apply the `delete-duplicates` primitive function, redefining a duplicate not as an element equal to another, but as subset of another. This is done through the key parameter `:test`, which is used to test if an element is equal (that is subset) of another.

Note that we can use `delete-duplicates` instead of the non-destructive version `remove-duplicates` since we have obtained a fresh copy of the list with `copy-list`.

**Addition**

The above function is defined by interpreting:

> remove any set that is a subset of any other set in the lists

as: remove from a *list* of sets all the *elements* X such that there is *another* element Y with X ⊆ Y.

---

Finally, here is a version of the function to be used in a more general contest. It is defined for sequences, not only for lists, has the two optional keyword parameters `:key` and `:test`, and *can destructively modify* the sequence passed to it (so, use with attention, and copy the sequence before passing if it must be reused or is a constant list).

```
(defun supersets (sets &key (key #'identity) (test #'eql))
  "Given a sequence of lists representing sets, remove all sets that are contained
in others. The input sequence can be modified. The keyword parameter :key is a function
that, applied to each element of the input list, returns the set that must be considered 
for the checking. The keyword parameter :test is a function used when testing
the equality for the elements of the set."
  (delete-duplicates
   (sort sets #'<= :key (lambda(x) (length (funcall key x))))
   :key key :test #'(lambda (set1 set2) (subsetp set1 set2 :test test))))

(supersets
  (copy-list '( ((1 2) (a)) ((1 2 3) (b)) ((3 2) (c)) ((4 5) (d)) ((5 4) (e)) ))
  :key #'car)   ; => (((4 5) (D)) ((1 2 3) (B)))

(supersets 
  #( ((1 2) (a)) ((1 2 3) (b)) ((3 2) (c)) ((4 5) (d)) ((5 4) (e)) ) 
 :key #'car)    ; => #(((5 4) (E)) ((1 2 3) (B)))

(supersets (copy-list '(("abc") ("bc" "abc"))) :test #'string=)
   ; => (("bc" "abc"))
```

Comment: Lots of learning here for me, thanks. But still not quite general enough. Superset to me means it applies to sets of elements (ie, sets of lisp objects), sets of sets of elements, sets of sets of sets, etc. I'm still not sure how to generalize the code to all sets--eg, (supersets (copy-list '( (a (b)) (c ((b) a)) )) -> ( (c ((b) a)) ) at the next level.

Comment: Then I suggest you to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then post a new question with a precise specification of your need.

Comment: Actually, your update looks like it should work for my planning app, since the set elements are trees rather than true sets. So the generalization to full sets, although perhaps interesting, is academic.

Answer (score 1):

If the definition of the problem is (as given in the post),

> remove any set that is a subset of any other set in the list

this would be a literal implementation (I used `CURRY` from alexandria. You could replace that with a regular `LAMBDA` if you can't have the dependency):

```
(defun supersets (sets)
  (remove-if (lambda (set)
               (some (curry #'subsetp set)
                     (remove set sets)))
             sets))

CL-USER> (supersets '((1 2) (1 2 3) (3 2) (3 5) (5 3)))
((1 2 3))
```

Notice that this removes `(3 5)` from the list as well, because it is `SUBSETP` of `(5 3)`. If you want to keep it, you could define a version of `SUBSETP` that considers equal lists not subsets. Of course, then you would have `(5 3)` in the result as well. I don't see any logical explanation for having `(3 5)`, but excluding `(5 3)`.

*Edit:* Here's also a version that leaves one of `(3 5)` and `(5 3)`.

```
(defun supersets (sets)
  (let ((sets (remove-duplicates sets :test #'set-equal)))
    (remove-if (lambda (set)
                 (some (curry #'subsetp set)
                       (remove set sets)))
               sets)))
```

*Another edit:* A bit more efficient version. This way it doesn't create new lists constantly with the `REMOVE`.

```
(defun supersets (sets)
  (remove-if (lambda (set)
               (some (lambda (set2)
                       (unless (eq set set2)
                         (subsetp set set2)))
                     sets))
             sets))
```

Comment: Note that you don't pass a `:test` argument to `remove`. I see two options:  `equal` or alexandria's `set-equal`, which might make more sense for that question.

Comment: @coredump Good point, but it's not really necessary to pass a `:TEST`, since the set is `EQ`, and thus `EQL`, to itself (and since all the elements are supposed to be lists, there shouldn't be any other elements that are `EQL` to the set). It might be better to pass the argument explicitly though. `SET-EQUAL` would be a good choice if you wan't to keep both `(3 5)` and `(5 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thought it might be interesting to time each of these 3 offered functions. (Not the best, but simply get the supersets of the given list of 5 sets 10M times under SBCL.)

```
davypough (me):  5.7 sec  4.8B cons
Renzo:           3.1      800M
jkiiski          5.0      2.2B
```

(Note: changed the first 2 "remove"s in jkiiski to "delete"s.)

If you don't mind a follow-up question, how does one estimate the computational complexity of some of these sequence functions (short of diving into the assembly code, or running experiments with increasing N and trying to discern the shape of the curve)? Eg, my guess is that a raw  delete-duplicates is n-squared?

Comment: 'changed the first 2 "remove"s in jkiiski to "delete"s' - You shouldn't do that. `DELETE` is a destructive operation, and you might be passing literal data to the function. Also, using `DELETE` inside the lambda would mess things up since you don't want to permanently modify it. If you want to optimize it, you could change the `SOME` to `(some (lambda (set2) (unless (eq set set2) (subsetp set set2))) sets)` so it doesn't have to make new lists constantly (with the `REMOVE`). I just wrote it that way for better readability.

Comment: After a quick check on the implementation that I used for answering (CCL), the function that deletes duplicates on lists uses a hash table if the size is greater than a certain threshold and the test can be used in hash tables (so the cost is linear with N). Since this is not the case (due to `subsetp`) the code of `delete-duplicates` seems to me of to be of order N² on the number of elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

@Renzo. Amazing. However, for my application I need to generalize your function to include :key and :test parameters. Eg, (supersets '( ((1 2) (a)) ((1 2 3) (b)) ((3 2) (c)) ((4 5) (d)) ((5 4) (e)) ) :key #'car :test #'equal) -> ( ((1 2 3) (b)) ((4 5) (d)) ), since the numbers are really lists and the top-level set items are pairs of lists. My attempt doesn't work. Can you see why?

```
(defun supersets (sets &key (key #'identity) (test #'eql))
  (delete-duplicates
    (sort (copy-list sets) 
          #'<= :key #'(lambda (set)
                        (length (funcall key set))))
    :test #'(lambda (set1 set2)
              (subsetp set1 set2 :key key :test test))))
```

(ps: also, I notice that if I simply rebind the input "sets" argument in a "let" (avoiding the "copy-list"), the time for 10M executions on the original example reduces to only 1 sec and 0 cons. Is this a general principle, or am I off-base? Thanks.

Comment: I modified the answer. But please note that adding an aswer to modify your question is not a correct practice on Stack Overflow. You should post any significant change to your question as a new question, citing the previous one.